# Docker container UUID

Tags: ubuntu, docker

Apparently, Docker containers share the same UUID. How can i have different values for each container on the same docker host?

I am running a program, consul, which apparently has issues with docker containers having the same UUID as throws this error:

```
   root@redis-2:/usr/local/bin# consul agent -config-dir /etc/consul.d/ -bind 172.17.0.3 &
[1] 428
root@kkbox-test-redis-2:/usr/local/bin# ==> WARNING: LAN keyring exists but -encrypt given, using keyring
==> Starting Consul agent...
==> Joining cluster...
==> 3 error(s) occurred:

* Failed to join 10.24.5.251: Member 'kkbox-test-redis-1' has conflicting node ID 'ec2484ee-2960-1781-6d95-3bd994e5f3bf' with this agent's ID
* Failed to join 10.24.5.252: Member 'kkbox-test-redis-1' has conflicting node ID 'ec2484ee-2960-1781-6d95-3bd994e5f3bf' with this agent's ID
* Failed to join 10.24.6.251: Member 'kkbox-test-redis-1' has conflicting node ID 'ec2484ee-2960-1781-6d95-3bd994e5f3bf' with this agent's ID
```

Is there a way to update the UUID in each container here?:

```
/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass `-disable-host-node-id` to `consul agent ...`, and consul will generate a random node ID at startup (rather than generate it from e.g. `/proc/sys/kernel/random/boot_id`).

Like this:

```
consul agent -disable-host-node-id -config-dir /etc/consul.d/ -bind 172.17.0.3 &
```

Alternatively, you could always generate the node ID yourself and pass it via the `-node-id` flag.

---

Also see [Consul join broken in containerized Servers run on same node](https://github.com/hashicorp/consul/issues/2877)

Comment: Thanks Thomas. The alternative seems to work. The first solution does not work for some reason.